# Javascript : Getting 'Use Strict' error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript. I am trying to spit something out to the Chrome Console but am getting these errors in JSLint in Brackets :

```
'$' was used before it was defined. $(document).on("ready", function() {
3   Expected exactly one space between 'function' and '('.  $(document).on("ready", function() {
4   Missing 'use strict' statement. console.log("Address Explorer JS up and running.");
4   Expected 'console' at column 5, not column 3.   console.log("Address Explorer JS up and running.");
4   'console' was used before it was defined.   console.log("Address Explorer JS up and running.");
```

Here is the JS code :

```
"use strict";
/* address-explorer.js */

$(document).on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Address Explorer JS up and running.");
});
```

I tried adding the 'Use Strict'; statement at the top of the file but these errors don't go away and nothing spits out to the console. Here is the HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Address Explorer</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./address-explorer.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="twelve coloumns">
            Your Account
        </h1>
        <div class="five coloumns">
            <span id="displayed_balance" class="value">&nbsp;</span>
            <br><span class="label"> Total Balance</span>
        </div>
        <div class="four coloumns">
            <span id="transaction_count" class="value">&nbsp;</span>
            <br><span class="label"> Transactions</span>
        </div>
        <div class="two coloumns">
            <span id="blocks_mined_count" class="value">&nbsp;</span>
            <br><span class="label">Blocks Mined</span>
        </div>
        <h4 class="twelve columns">Activity</h4>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a JSLinter? These look like lint errors -- if so, you need to specify develop mode. Some constant globals like console, or window will throw this error. Ignore it.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't loaded jQuery...

Comment: @Meeseeks I have added the jQuery script , and both the html and js are in the same file.

Comment: You've to configure JSLint: Assume: browser and add `$` and `console` to Global variables list. JSLint also thinks, that a correct place for "use strict" declaration is in a function.

Comment: it might be due to some non-supported encoding character, might be added by your IDE or you mistakenly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These look like lint errors -- if so, you need to specify develop mode. Some constant globals like console, or window will throw this error. Ignore it.

I'm not sure why `on("ready"` doesn't work -- that's what called `.ready()` internally. I'm working on finding out why. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/09tL9wtn/) for an example of your code working.

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
```

Should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Comment: well... technically `$(document).on("ready", function() {` isn't wrong, it just isn't a good practice for a few reasons (unless it has been removed in a recent version and i'm just not aware)

Comment: @KevinB I wonder why `.on("ready"` didn't trigger then. I thought it was right too (I should reword my statement..), but the console statement didn't run with the original. Maybe there is a change I'm unaware of as well.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b3011d5e5529a899e4cb79df520a4e5f  It didn't run with ready either. Is my jQuery tag correct in html ?

Comment: The only case where it wouldn't run is if the event was defined *after* it has already triggered, which shouldn't be the case here. odd indeed.

Comment: If the jquery script inclusion was wrong you'd see an error too.

Comment: @KevinB my thoughts lie with his IDE. He doesn't seem to be developing with an IDE I've used before.. it may be scoping or doing something differently we're not aware of.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I am using Brackets

Comment: @SterlingArcher You were right. There was something wrong with the IDE. It works with Sublime Text. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you were able to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is only one way to fix your linting issues, but you should put your JS into an `Immediately Invoked Function`, and declare that functions scope to use `"use strict";`

Also, pass jQuery in as a dependency of your `IIF` and use the jslint directives to tell jslint what you're expecting.  In our case, we are saying that we are using a browser `browser:true` which means `document` and many other browser specific globals will pass defined linting.  `devel: true` means that `console` should be considered defined as well.

You have an external global, `jQuery` if you are including jQuery before this source, so you need to tell jslint to expect that as well.  We do this with the `/*global ...*/` directive.

```
/*jslint browser:true, devel: true*/
/*global jQuery*/
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        console.log("Address Explorer JS up and running.");
    });
}(jQuery));
```